# Unix write permissions

Tags: unix, permissions

I recently configured by Ubuntu server for SFTP on my `www` directory.

Permissions `0755`, and FileZilla would connect, however it said I didn't have write permissions and rejected my uploads.

I found that I forgot to `sudo chown [myuser] www` to remove the owner from being `root`.

That being said -- why was the `root` with the same permissions as the admin `user` rejecting uploads? Can you simply not remote access a directory owned by the `root`?

Comment: What do you mean by "why was the `root` with ..."? Do you mean "why was ownership by `root`"?

Comment: Also you have not stated what user you connect with. `myuser`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot give definitive answer without knowing owning group of the file, but anyway:

Permissions `755` mean that file is writable by its owner and not-writable by others. So if file owner is `root`, only `root` can write it. If you connect with `myuser` (I assume, you have not stated that), you do not have write permissions.

Also note that any file is writable by `root`, no matter what the permissions are. So once the file is owned by `myuser`, keeping the same permissions, it is writable by both `myuser` and `root`.